# sidebarMenu does not function properly when using includeHTML

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am using Rshinydashboard and I have ran into an issue when I try and include a html document in my app using includeHTML. Once the menuItems & menSubItems are expanded, they can not be retracted. I have explored other solutions and have found none. If you have any idea what may be the problem or have another way of including a html report in an app I would appreciate your help. Please see the code below and help if you can!

Create a RMD file to create a html report (if you don't have one lying around)

```
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---
## Test HTML Document
This is just a test.
```

Build a Test html Report

```
# Build Test HTML file
rmarkdown::render(
  input = "~/test.rmd",
  output_format = "html_document",
  output_file = file.path(tempdir(), "Test.html")
)
```

Build Test App

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "sidebarmenu",
      menuItem(
        "A", tabName = "a",  icon = icon("group", lib="font-awesome"),
        menuSubItem("AA", tabName = "aa"),
        conditionalPanel(
          "input.sidebarmenu === 'aa'",
          sliderInput("b", "Under sidebarMenu", 1, 100, 50)
        ),
        menuSubItem("AB", tabName = "ab")
      )
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "a", textOutput("texta")),
      tabItem(tabName = "aa", textOutput("textaa"), uiOutput("uia")),
      tabItem(tabName = "ab", textOutput("textab"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$texta <- renderText("showing tab A")
  output$textaa <- renderText("showing tab AA")
  output$textab <- renderText("showing tab AB")
  output$uia <- renderUI(includeHTML(path = file.path(tempdir(), "Test.html")))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I think one or more of the javascript library imports in the rmarkdown file is conflicting with the javascript libraries that get loaded from Shiny.  You can render("~/test.rmd", html_document(self_contained = F)).  Comment out all the <script src="xyz.js" /> lines and the bug goes away, but this is not much of a solution.

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/0UiiHcdhN4k for a discussion about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*That is because you included a complete HTML file in the shiny UI, and 
you should only include the content between `<body>` and `</body>`* (quoted from yihui)

A solution could be to run an extra line to fix your `Test.html` automatically after running `rmarkdown::render()`:

`xml2::write_html(rvest::html_node(xml2::read_html("Test.html"), "body"), file = "Test2.html")`

and then have

`output$uia <- renderUI(includeHTML(path = file.path(tempdir(), "Test2.html")))`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This solution worked perfectly for me and is a great help! I think @Ben is correct that it is an issue with conflicting javascript libraries. This solution avoids Rmarkdown javascript libraries being included in the html file by just taking the body of the html file.

Comment: @RolandASc What if the <head> tags have some JS, CSS defined for the specific code that is used by the body ? How to address that ? Appreciate your response

Comment: Same problem, the solution work for me but I have some JS and CSS defined that I want to keep ..

Answer (score -1):

You just forget about curly brackets - renderUI need an expression as argument.

renderUI(**{** includeHTML(...) **}**)

Code

```
  output$uia <- renderUI({includeHTML(path = file.path(tempdir(), "Test.html"))})
```

works fine.

Or you can use this code

```
output$uia <- renderUI(includeMarkdown(path = file.path("test.rmd")))
```

In this case you need to specify the path to the file test.rmd, here it is located in the same directory with source file.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I found that this does not change anything and I don't see how the curly brackets would change anything. Typically curly brackets are used to encompass a block of code than spans multiple lines. The menuItems and menuSubItems still do not work as they should. Once the menuSubItems are shown they can not be hidden again (by clicking the "A" tab).

Comment: @Jason, how we can see in [documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.1/renderUI.html), method "renderUI" has an argument expr which is an expression. That means we must use curly brackets in any case - automatic conversion of function includeHTML to expression not provided.

Comment: @Jason, maybe this will be helpful:

`output$uia <- renderUI(includeMarkdown(path = file.path("test.rmd")))`

In this case you need to specify the path to the file test.rmd, here it is located in the same directory with source file.

Comment: I also do not see what the curly brackets are supposed to do. But the workaround of using a markdown file works for me.

Comment: Additionally I think including the html-file inside a shiny Rmarkdown code might work as well.